# mailx Not Sending Email

Tags: linux, email, command-line-interface, centos7

I installed mailx in my Linux webserver running CentOS 7. When I try to send a test email,

```
echo "Body test." | mail -r "fromemail@domain.com" -s "Subject Test" toemail@domain.com
```

I check my email and don't receive anything. However, if I use the mailq command, I get this:

```
postqueue: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
7805D2DF        422 Wed Jan 11 15:00:40  fromemail@domain.com
                                         toemail@domain.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mailx is a client, you still need an MTA like postfix/sendmail/exim, or specify a server

```
$ mailx -v -s "$EMAIL_SUBJECT" \
-S smtp=smtp://smtp.ust.hk \
-S from="$FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS($FRIENDLY_NAME)" \
$TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

[source](http://www.systutorials.com/5167/sending-email-using-mailx-in-linux-through-internal-smtp/)

[Another Example](https://www.jacobdevans.com/qmail-outbound-email-monitor-blacklist-prevention-script/)

(options vary but I think this is right for rhl)